# Fantasy movie where the protagonist gets a broken sword and forge welds it

Tags: story-identification, movie, conan

The film is not modern (1970-1990), similar to *Conan the Destroyer*, or maybe a remake. Or a TV series. I was young so I don't remember.

The film contained a scene where the protagonist gets a broken sword and forge welds it. Then he performs feats. Bodybuilder, looks like Schwarzenegger (maybe it was him).

Answer (score 4):

The reforging of a sword is a central element in the opera *Siegfried* and the ancient *Nibelungen Lied* it is based on. There have been several movies based on either, but the one that looks the best match to your description is 2004 TV movie *[Ring of the Nibelungs](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0387541/)* (variously titled *The Curse of the Ring*, *Sword of Xanten*, and *Dark Kingdom: The Dragon King*), starring Benno Fürmann, Kristanna Loken, Alicia Witt, and Max von Sydow. Judging from the trailer, it looks fairly old-fashioned, so could be mistaken as being older than it is.The hero looks more like Kevin Sorbo than Schwarzenegger, though.

[image]

Another possibility is a 1966-67 adaptation in two parts, *[Die Nibelungen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Nibelungen_(1966%E2%80%9367_film))*; a remake of Fritz Lang's 1924 silent movie two-parter or the same name (which is amazing, but probably not what you're looking for).

[image]

Not having seen either of these two adaptations, I don't know if the sword-reforging scene is in any of them. There may also be non-Siegfried/Nibelung movies with reforging of a sword, but the only one that comes to mind is *The Lord of the Rings*.